# Logic Invalidity

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm having trouble with a problem in Propositional Logic Using induction I am supposed to show that if a well formed formula (wff) X has no repetitions of sentence letters then X is invalid.

The hint in the back of the book says "Instead of trying to show directly that every wff without repetition of sentence letters has the feature of PL-invalidity, find some feature F that is stronger than PL-invalidity (i.e. some feature from which PL-invalidity follows), and prove that every wff has that feature."

What does invalidity follow from?

Comment: even guesses would help at this point everyone

Comment: Are you sure about the statement of your problem ? If we work with *predicate logic*, the formula $\forall x \alpha \rightarrow \alpha(x/t)$ is *valid*, but it has **no** repetition of "sentence letters". With "sentence letter" do you mean : $p, q, \ldots$ of *propositional calculus* ?

Comment: Googling the sentence in quotes identifies the textbook as Sider's *Logic for Philosophy*... and the problem (2.8) is indeed about propositional logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show that every wff with no repeated sentence letters is [satisfiable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisfiability). This is pretty easy by using the [disjunctive normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form). This implies that the negation of such a wff (which also has no repeated sentence letters) cannot be a tautology, i.e. it's invalid.

Comment: Thank you for your help! That worked perfectly.